# Best practices about paths while working localhost

Tags: php, path, laravel-5

I use laravel 5 to build some of my projects. In my controller usually I use redirect to a specific path like:

```
return redirect("http://localhost/myproject/public/all-posts");
```

I would like to build absolute paths while working localhost so as all of the url works fine when the project is going to be uploaded to the server.
Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write it like this and it will return you to all-posts.

return redirect("/all-posts");

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should have a set of `ini` files which would define a `baseUrl` per deployment, like: `development.ini`, `staging.ini`, `production.ini`, `tests.ini`.

And then include and parse the right ini file based off condition, for example URL:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_HOST'], 'localhost') !== false) {
    //localhost
} else if (strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_HOST'], 'domain') !== false) {
    //production
}
```

Check out `parse_ini_file()` function docs for the info of how to use it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php